# A simple .bat file for opening mysql console in Windows?

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

It seems like on linux machines, its super easy to access mysql console, you simply type `mysql` and you're put into mysql console, where you can then type `SELECT bla FROM foo` and the query is executed, etc.

On windows however, it seems like you have to type `C:\mysql\bin\bla-bla\something.exe` each time.

Is there a way to, for example, make a .bat file that each time I open, it opens the command prompt with mysql console already selected?

Specifically this is about windows xp.

Comment: Have you investigated that obscure thing called the PATH variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add it to your PATH.

Control Panel > System > Environment Variables > Scroll down to Path under System Variables and click edit, then add the path to your mysql.exe.

Comment: @Adem I did, each time I type 'mysql' I get 'mysql is not a recognized bla bla bla'

Comment: Do you have spaces in your path to MySQL?

Comment: No, this is the path: `C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.36\bin\mysql.exe`. I've added it to both the SYSTEM section and current user section. I've set the variable name as `mysql` and the `value` as the full path above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think my original answer was clear enough. You don't want to create a new system variable, but rather modify the existing variable that is named "Path." Make sure that you separate each path in the Path variable with a semicolon. For example, mine looks like this: `d:\ruby\bin;d:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client;D:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;d:\server\php;d:\server\apache\bin;d:\Program Files\Git\cmd;d:\server\mysql\bin;D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin`

Comment: Cheers! That worked! The only thing is, now I get a password error, and have to type the whole `mysql -h localhost -u root` string in order to start. Is there a way to make a .bat file which will take care of this initial command?

Comment: If it's on your localhost you can connect like this: `mysql -uuser -ppassword`. Just switch out "user" and "password" for your actual username and password.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your environment variable PATH the path to where mysql is installed, you won't need a bat file

Answer (score 1):

Set PATH variable to point where you want.

Or, make a script that you put somewhere where PATH is set to.

That should help.

Answer (score 1):

If you added the mysql\bin directory to your path, you would be able to just type mysql too.

If you right click my computer, properties, advanced system settings, down the bottom environment variables. Now add the path to mysql\bin to your path, next console window you open (and forever more) mysql as a command will work

Answer (score 0):

While adding the `C:\mysql\bin\bla-bla` directory to the path as other answers have mentioned will work fine, I dislike adding to the path just to get a single command to work.  The path environment variable on my machine is cluttered enough as it is.

What I typically do is have a small batch file for this in a `c:\util` directory that is in the path (specifically to be able to drop these little scripts or basic, no-install, utility programs):

```
@C:\mysql\bin\bla-bla\something.exe %*
```

That one line in an file named `c:\util\mysql.cmd` will let me run the program and pass it a set of command line arguments.  Windows does complicate things a bit if you want that program to start in another window and not block-up the command window that you ran the batch file from.  For that situation you need to invoke the command using something like the `start` command (kind of the equivalent to ending the command with `&` on Unix):

```
@start "" "C:\mysql\bin\bla-bla\something.exe" %*
```

Note that the empty quoted argument is necessary if you're going to put the command inside quotes because of the way that `start` interprets the first quoted argument (as a window title).

Comment: Sorry but not what I asked for. Having to type `C:\util\mysql.cmd` each time is also quite cumbersome.

Comment: Note: `c:\util` is in the path specifically for "these little scripts or basic, no-install, utility programs". I'm not sure how people can work effectively on Windows without having some sort of utility directory in the path. But that's just me.  With that 'fix', all you need to type is `mysql`.

Answer (score -1):

```
@echo OFF
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
c:
cd "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\"
mysql.exe  --user="root" --password="the password"
```

Comment: There is no relevance to the question

Comment: Reffering to the topic question: "A simple .bat file for opening mysql console in Windows?". You put that in a .bat file and when you double click you are in the console logged automatically, no need to write manually username and password every time you log into mysql console, this way you just double click and you are in. I searched for this but couldn't find it, so I made this solution, and I added it here, so it can help others who need it.